# Rails: Print to page, not to console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, helper

I want to write a helper method to print a list of radio buttons.  The obvious way to do it is to have the helper method return a string of html code for my view file to render.

But that's just not pretty, appending `<li>` after `<li>` to a string, then returning it.

The code would be more readable, of course, if I could just **print each line of html in turn**.  Can I print lines to an output stream and have it end up on my page (not on the server console)?

(I'm using rails 2.3.5, btw.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build up a list in a helper method by calling `content_tag` and passing in the desired element and a block that renders some HTML (like the `radio_button` helper), then joining the whole mess into a string, e.g. *(air code)*:

```
module SomeHelper
  def radio_button_list(things)
    things.collect do |thing|
      content_tag(:li) { radio_button(thing.foo, thing.bar, thing.baz) }
    end.join
  end
end
```

Comment: It's best practice to use concat around the content_tag here rather than `join` at the end. This is exceptionally helpful if you've got multiple levels of nesting.

Comment: I had considered concatenating a long string, then outputting to the page.  It lacks the cleanliness I had hoped to achieve, but I suppose there's nothing else for it.  Thank you.